# Save List<Object> to instance state with Parcelable

Tags: android, arraylist, android-recyclerview, android-savedstate

I have the following models:

**GitItem:**

```
    public class GitItem implements Serializable, Parcelable {
        public int id;
        public String name;
        public String full_name;
        public GitOwner owner;

        public GitItem() {
        }

        public GitItem(Parcel in) {
            id = in.readInt();
            name = in.readString();
            full_name = in.readString();
        }

        public int describeContents() {
            return 0;
        }

        public void writeToParcel(Parcel out, int flags){
            out.writeInt(id);
            out.writeString(name);
            out.writeString(full_name);
        }

        public static final Parcelable.Creator<GitItem> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<GitItem>(){

            @Override
            public GitItem createFromParcel(Parcel source) {
                return new GitItem(source);
            }

            @Override
            public GitItem[] newArray(int size) {
                return new GitItem[size];
            }
        };
    }
```

**and GitOwner:**

```
public class GitOwner implements Serializable, Parcelable {
    public String avatar_url;

    public GitOwner(Parcel in) {
        avatar_url = in.readString();
    }

    public GitOwner() {
    }

    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {

    }

    public static final Parcelable.Creator<GitOwner> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<GitOwner>(){

        @Override
        public GitOwner createFromParcel(Parcel source) {
            return  new GitOwner(source);
        }

        @Override
        public GitOwner[] newArray(int size) {
            return new GitOwner[size];
        }
    };
}
```

and then in **MainActivity.java** I have a `List<GitItem> data;` which is bound to my `RecyclerView`.

Basically what I am trying to achieve, is to store current state of my `List<GitItem>` when I change `Activity` or simply rotate device. Unfortunately, even though I have implemented `Parcelable` (as suggested by other posts), I was unable to store the instance.

Any help in this matter would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have not implemented the complete body of `Parcelable` functions i.e `writeToParcel` in `GitOwner` and `GitItem` class

In `GitOwner` class

```
@Override
public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
     dest.writeString(avatar_url);
     // add this line
}
```

and inside `GitItem` use [`writeParcelable`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcel.html#writeParcelable(android.os.Parcelable,%20int)) to write and [`readParcelable`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcel.html#readParcelable(java.lang.ClassLoader)) to read `GitItem` object otherwise it won't be persisted and restored

```
    public GitItem(Parcel in) {
        id = in.readInt();
        name = in.readString();
        full_name = in.readString();
        owner = in.readParcelable(GitItem.class.getClassLoader());
        // Add line to read owner object
    }

    public void writeToParcel(Parcel out, int flags){
        out.writeInt(id);
        out.writeString(name);
        out.writeString(full_name);
        out.writeParcelable(owner , flags);           
        // Add line to write owner object
    }
```